# Allow only "Select" statement for queries executed through PHP

Tags: php, sql, select

I have made a form that accepts query and executes it through php.
I would like to apply a check on the input that only select statement is allowed for queries.
How can i achieve that ?

Comment: Regex is the first thing that comes to my mind ..

Comment: You should in any case create a user for the server/php that is only allowed to "SELECT" in your MySQL database, so no matter how good or bad your checking performs users will only be able to "SELECT".

Comment: Connect to database as a user to whom are granted only read privileges?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Best way is if you have access to your database server and can create a new user, create a user with only a SELECT privilege, then assign that user to your php web application.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Regex is fine, but it's a bit of a risky method to filter it out that way, you'll never know how creative your user can be :)

Comment: @aF. +1 for "what sorcery is this"

Comment: Absolutely Perfect Idea to go with rather than making server to process this for you ask DB to do it for you.....

Comment: You should always create a `webuser` for your mysql queries, never use the `root` user

Comment: I'm assuming separate user for each web app is a given standard, the answer is about privilege :)

Answer (score 5):

To be safe, you could create a MySQL user and only give that user [`SELECT` permissions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges).